# Autohotkey: How to program to walk in 2D game

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I'm writing a macro for a 2D game. The coordinates for the character are given, in (x,y). There are obstacles in the game, so I need to program in a way that the character moves around it.

So I've written a program that reads the memory of x and y coordinates of the game. Then I wrote a function that moves the character to a desired position. The logic is: if x coordinate is less than the desired position, keep moving right, and vice versa. Then, if y coordinate is less than the desired position, keep moving up, and vice versa.

However, because of the obstacles, I have to manually give the coordinates to move to. For example, if I was at (1,1), and told the character to move to (5,5), there might be an obstacle at (3,1) and the character will get stuck. So I'll tell it to move to (1,3) first, then move to (5,3), then (5,5).

I'm just confused on how to SEQUENTIALLY tell the character to move. AFTER I move to (1,3), move to (5,3), then (5,5).

This is what I have:

```
    f1::

WinGetTitle, ai, A
curX := ReadMemory(0x10F6A7D0, ai)
curY := ReadMemory(0x10F6A7D4, ai)

MoveTo(21,13)
if(curX == 21 && curY == 13){
    MoveTo(21,28)
}

return


q::

Pause

return


ReadMemory(MADDRESS,PROGRAM)
{
winget, pid, PID, %PROGRAM%

VarSetCapacity(MVALUE,4,0)
ProcessHandle := DllCall("OpenProcess", "Int", 24, "Char", 0, "UInt", pid, "UInt")
DllCall("ReadProcessMemory","UInt",ProcessHandle,"UInt",MADDRESS,"Str",MVALUE,"UInt",4,"UInt *",0)

Loop 4
result += *(&MVALUE + A_Index-1) << 8*(A_Index-1)

return, result  
}



MoveTo(targetX,targetY)
{

xadd = 0x10F6A7D0
yadd = 0x10F6A7D4

WinGetTitle, ai, A

Loop{
    curX:= ReadMemory(xadd,ai)
    curY:= ReadMemory(yadd,ai)

    if(curX < targetX){
        ControlSend,, {Right}, %ai%
    }
    else if(curX > targetX){
        ControlSend,, {Left}, %ai%
    }
    else if(curY < targetY){
        ControlSend,, {Down}, %ai%
    }
    else if(curY > targetY){
        ControlSend,, {Up}, %ai%
    }
Sleep, 30
```

Comment: Where in your script are you checking/accounting for obstacles?

Comment: I code it so it avoids the obstacles alltogether. The maps are not random, so I can tell the character to move to a certain spot so it avoids them.

Comment: Which part of the code is it then?

Comment: You need the way how to call `MoveTo()` function several time so it will move your character? You want to give parameters to `MoveTo()` function manually, like to put parameters each time in GUI?

Comment: For example, I need the char to move to (1,13) -> (16,13) -> (16,25) and so forth. I don't know how to program it so once it finishes moving to a certain spot, it makes the next move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I solved my problem. I just had to make a while-loop in the MoveTo function and terminate it once I reach the position.

```
MoveTo(targetX,targetY)
{

xadd = 0x10F6A7D0
yadd = 0x10F6A7D4

WinGetTitle, ai, A
isThere := 1

while(isThere = 1){
    curX:= ReadMemory(xadd,ai)
    curY:= ReadMemory(yadd,ai)

    if(curX < targetX){
        ControlSend,, {Right}, %ai%
    }
    else if(curX > targetX){
        ControlSend,, {Left}, %ai%
    }
    else if(curY < targetY){
        ControlSend,, {Down}, %ai%
    }
    else if(curY > targetY){
        ControlSend,, {Up}, %ai%
    }

    if(curX = targetX && curY = targetY){
          isThere = 0
     }
Sleep, 30
```